# New Job Offers Spam - Defeats SpamAssassin

Tags: spam, spamassassin

For the last month or so I've noticed a shift in spam content.

Basically still getting a lot of it but there's a new focus on fake jobs offers.

They all look the same, all take to a fake Seek.com payment page.

The main difference though is SpamAssassin on the mail server is *Not* detecting those as spam (whereas all the usual manhood spam stuff does).

Why do these get not flagged as spam? any tweaks to the server that can help?

Comment: You could add your own spamassassin filter to flag those seek.com job ad spam messages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I started using using Spamhaus's Zen DNSBL and their DROP list it's cut down the e-mail even getting to SA by 99%. Zen is a combination list of IPs that have been blocked because of known open relays, past spam violations, or their netblock owner has policy-listed them. The DROP list is a list of IPs known to be owned by businesses that send spam.

I really like SA, but taking a layered approach to e-mail filtering seems to work best these days. My MTAs also check SPF and strictly follow the record.

Comment: Found this info on setting this up on Plesk for those interested: http://www.rackaid.com/resources/7-easy-steps-to-improve-email-service-on-plesk/

Comment: And this side note is interesting: http://mattiasgeniar.be/2009/01/14/using-plesks-smtp-server-dns-blacklist-prevents-sending/

Comment: Not meaning to offend the people who wrote that article; but it sounds like they have no business configuring an SMTP server if they're running DNSBL on authenticated SMTP connections. Securing a SMTP server isn't rocket science, and the server should have a default configuration to disable certain checks (spam mainly) for specifically authorized users. I suppose it's something worth being aware of if Plesk has that bug.